# What does 主様 mean in SNS?

Tags: meaning

I've received something like

> 主様すごいです

but I don't know what it means and when I translate it, it turns out to be something like

> "master is amazing"

or something like that. Either way what does 主様 mean?

Answer (score 10):

主 in this case means someone who posts it. It is originated from net slang "うｐ主".

"うｐ" is "up". Please try to type "up" by Japanese keyboard. It should be "うｐ".
("おｋ" is also net slang as "O.K.". Type "ok" by Japanese keyboard. It is "おｋ" as well.)

"up" means "upload". In Japanese, you can say "アップする" (upload something)" when you make a bulletin board online or post a picture/movie in SNS.
（"アップ" = up = upload）

Next, 主 in this "うｐ主" means...

> **主{Nushi}**
> 動作・行為の主体。また、ある事柄の主人公。「声の主」「うわさの主」 (quoted from デジタル大辞泉)
> Subject that do something or the main character in a issue or event.
> "声の主{Koe-no-nushi}" = someone/something that speaks something
> "うわさの主{Uwasa-no-nushi}" = someone who is gossiped about. (**NOT "someone who gossips"**)

So, "うｐ主" means "アップした人", that is someone who uploaded(/posted) something.
Then, they got to use just "主".

様 is Japanese honorifics, which is used when you respect someone or in buisness.

> 田中様{Tanaka-sama}

Therefore,

> （うｐ）主様｛Nushi-sama}すごいです
> You are amazing.

Comment: So, this seems like the equivalent to the English slang "OP" (original poster)?

Comment: Yes, it looks like original poster. Strictly speaking, "OP" is translated as "スレ主", which means "someone who makes a bulletin board for a theme online (it is called thread in Japan.)".   

  "スレ" stands for "thread" (スレッド）.

In the first place, スレ主 is the first case of "～主" as net slang.  And, "うｐ" was used as "upload". 
 Then, some start to use ”うｐ主”  combining "スレ主" and "うｐ".

Finally, うｐ主 is used as someone uploads something..

Comment: Now, it seems that "うｐ主" is as same as "スレ主", but I think someone upload/post something is basically called "うｐ主" as a slang word.

Comment: Worth noting that in Christian contexts, 主様 could probably be read as しゅさま, referring to the Lord.

Comment: @Panzercrisis, Thank you for your comment. Indeed, 主 has many means and pronounciations.. . I am not a christian, but they may not say "主様" in Japan. I often see/hear the word  "主イエス・キリスト" or just "主" that means the Lord. Jesus Christ. I have never seen/heard anything but "主" in hymm. However, I also often see/hear ”教主様{kyoshu-sama}”, which means "founder of religion". Especially used for a founder of a new religion, I think.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it was related to ご主人様　(your husband) but I was wrong.
It turns out that ”主様” means you but only used on the SNS.

Exemple I found on the internet

> 主様凄くオシャレで憧れます
> You have good sense and I really admire you!